# How i can make invite logger with Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (gm) => {
    await gm.guild.channels.cache.get('812398572095668224').send(`${gm} was invited to the server by\n${member that invited him}`)
});
```

what i need to write in ${member that invited him}?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that may work:

```js
let savedInvs;
(async () => {
savedInvs = await <Guild>.fetchInvites() //replace <Guild> with your guild object
})()

client.on('inviteCreate', invite => {
savedInvs.set(invite.code, invite)
})
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async gm => {
//maybe checking if it’s the right guild
let newInvs = await gm.guild.fetchInvites();
let usedInv;
newInvs.forEach(inv => {
let val = savedInvs.find(in => in.uses < inv.uses)
if(val) usedInv = val
})
gm.guild.channels.cache.get('...').send(`${gm} was invited by ${usedInv.inviter}`)
savedInvs = newInvs;
})
```